# Using parameters with Embedder

Tags: plugins

[Embedder](https://github.com/A-P/Embedder) offers up some cool functionality, but I don't see where it explains how to set video parameters. It says you can, but not seeing how. Anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the previous example and format your own code to match.

Instead of

```
youtube_showinfo="0"
```

it goes in as

```
youtube_showinfo:0
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has an example and a list of supported parameters.

You basically pass a configuration object into the Embedder function. For example in this case I am setting `max_width` and `max_height`:

```
{{ craft.embedder.embed (entry.videoField, {max_width:500, max_height:800}) }}
```

Are you looking for a specific parameter?

Comment: It took me a few minutes to realize that the notes were formatted wrong. Once I swapped out the '=' with ':' it all came together.