# Vimeo video with Embedder plugin

Tags: plugin-embedder

I am relatively new to Craft and I came across the lovely plugin [Embedder](https://github.com/A-P/Embedder) and I have managed to make good use of it.

For some reason, I don't manage to apply the paramters. I have followed the advice on the following [post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9430/using-parameters-with-embedder) but still, don't manage to apply the vimeo paramters.

My code looks like that:

```
{% set video = craft.embedder.url(entry.workVideo, {max_width:5000, max_height:8000, vimeo_color:ffffff}) %}

{% if video %}
    <div class="work_video">
        {{ video.embed_code }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

All is fine beside the fact that the `vimeo_color` parameter doesn't work. I have tried other parameters like `vimeo_autoplay:true` also with no success.

Comment: I'm voting to "leave open" because it **does not** appear to be a bug report, and looks more likely to be user error.

Comment: This question was also posted to Github (presumably by OP)... https://github.com/A-P/Embedder/issues/11

Comment: @Lindsey, I already suggested to put the value in quotes, but deleted the answer, as the OP said it didn't fix the issue. Looks like it's not a syntax problem.

Comment: @carlcs I think you were on the right track, and was mainly echoing what you originally said. Because without quotes, **Twig reads that as a variable, not a string.** I only made a point about it because the OP's Github example _still_ didn't have quotes around that string.

Comment: @carlcs I'd actually wager that the quotes were the right answer, and the OP simply misunderstood you. You're spot on 99% of the time, why would this instance be any different? ;)

Comment: Lol, @Lindsey. Undeleted the answer and we will see if it was just a problem of my english (which unfortunatelly isn't 99% at all ...)! ;)

Comment: Great! With any luck, the plugin developer will help them figure it out, and we can port the correct answer back here.

Comment: The issue I have encounter was not due to misunderstanding how to use the plugin but due to the video itself. It was of a vimeo plus account with specific styling that couldn't be overwritten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of the plugin here - @Lindsey is correct - wrapping the color in quotes is the correct syntax. If you test it with this video, it works fine:
https://vimeo.com/130900978

One thing to note - with Vimeo, a video owner can overwrite this option - so if they set it to a specific theme color, you can't change it through this embed parameter. For more info on the Vimeo API, you can see this documentation: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding

Comment: In all fairness, I just reiterated the solution that @carlcs originally posted. Thanks for adding the official solution! And great note about the video owner's settings, probably a tricky thing to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you! This was actually my problem. The video I was embedding was of a Vimeo Plus account with specific embedding setting that couldn't be overwritten. Maybe it is just important to notice that only Vimeo plus and pro users can overwrite styling options.

Comment: And it was not only the `vimeo_color` parameter that couldn't be overwritten, I have tried also `vimeo_autoplay` and I assume that other things won't work too. All together, great plugin!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to format the parameter like so:

`vimeo_color: 'FFFFFF'`

**Update:**

It is the right code I posted. So make sure to wrap the value in quotes, as otherwise Twig reads `FFFFFF` as a variable. Only numbers or a boolean `false` or `true` can be passed without.

**And then, after you got your syntax right**, go to CP Settings → Tools → Empty Cache and clear your "Data Caches". I just installed the plugin to test it and found out it uses caching and doesn't take into account that the user could change these parameters.

Comment: I have tried but I was not surprised that it didn't work. When you embed vimeo video, the color code is without #...

Comment: What about `vimeo_color: 'FFFFFF'`

Comment: I must admit, I have tried this one too and some other more but still no success...

Comment: Ok, then I can't help. A string value should be in quotes, only numbers or booleans can be passed without. Without the quotes Twig looks for a variable FFFFFF.

Comment: Did you try using the other output tags the plugin provides? *(sorry for just guessing here, but I never used the plugin)*

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use the `vimeo_autoplay` and it didn't work as well. That's why I was asking if someone did manage to setup and parameter...

Comment: Great update @carlcs! And you even downloaded and tested the plugin yourself... I'm impressed! :)